# JAVA path error in hadoop

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, path, terminal

I installed hadoop watching a youtube video.
while I try to run this in terminal it gives me this error

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop     version
/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop: line 144:     /usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I have java in /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/ but I dont know why the error is showing a different path.

I have setup the path in hadoop-env.sh like this

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

I did the same in .bashrc

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop
JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Please help me. if you need any extra info please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` should point to `/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31` and not the `bin` folder under it.

Also, usually it would be `lib` and not `iib`.

The `PATH` should include the `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, though.

Comment: I changed as you said but it still giving me this error: srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop version /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop: line 144: /usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: So make sure `JAVA_HOME` points to the directory where you actually have a Java installation

Comment: in usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/ there are java,javac,javaws etc files are there

Comment: Is it really "iib" and not "lib"?

Comment: now its working well and fine . thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to change JAVA_HOME from:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/
```

TO

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31
```

i.e. Remove bin directory from JAVA_HOME variable.

And change PATH from:

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

TO

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: I changed as you said but it still giving me this error srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop version
/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop: line 144: /usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: thank you man. its a typo mistake I wrote "iib" instead of "lib" :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I saw you problem.you may be no install jdk or your jdk's path is wrong.
now you can test it :

1. test you jdk location:  `whereis java`
2. found your path and type it:`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/`
3. `export JRE_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31
   export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$ClASSPATH
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH`

   done it .Then you type hadoop path
   all type in  `~/.bashrc`